# Convert xml to html via xslt i tag in p tag

Tags: html, xml, xslt, type-conversion

First, sorry for my English, it's kind of rusty.
I'm new here and after spending a day on finding a solution, I finally ask my question here.
I have to convert a XML file to a HTML file using XSLT.
I've started by a template that match a "body" node then display the html.

My issue is that in my XML, I have html tag in html tag + text content like:

```
<text1>
     <p>*content*<i>*content*</i>*content*</p>
</text1>
```

Since there's a possibility of multiple `<text1>` node, I have a `<xsl: for-each select="text1>` in which I added another xsl: for-each to display the `<p>`tags.
This works but I can't have the `<i>`tags in my `<p>`s.
Once again this is my first question and I hope my issue is clear.
Thank you.

**Edit:** I've tried using templates but now the output doesn't display my html special characters: "Sbastien" should display "Sébastien". The dtd is available to the XML parser. I'm using libxslt.

#### My XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "wk-presse.dtd">
<article id="BC102400301">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <titre>
            Un r&ocirc;le &agrave; jouer durant le quinquennat
        </titre>
        <texte1>
            <p>
                La France a donc un nouveau pr&eacute;sident en la personne d&rsquo;Emmanuel Macron. Un pr&eacute;sident jeune, entreprenant, &eacute;conomiste et r&eacute;solument europ&eacute;en...
            </p>
            <p>
                Plus que jamais le transport sera donc la cl&eacute; du succ&egrave;s &eacute;conomique, pourvu que les transporteurs s&rsquo;appliquent &agrave; eux-m&ecirc;mes ces principes d&rsquo;innovation et de remise en question. Les pistes sont nombreuses: digitalisation, services, interconnexions, &eacute;nergies durables, accessibilit&eacute;s&hellip; Pourvu qu&rsquo;il s&rsquo;&eacute;loigne de l&rsquo;image surann&eacute;e du transport collectif du XX
                <sup>
                    <sup>
                        e
                    </sup>
                    si&egrave;cle
                </sup>
                , le transport routier de voyageurs moderne a donc un beau r&ocirc;le &agrave; jouer durant les cinq prochaines ann&eacute;es.
            </p>
        </texte1>
    </body>
</article>
```

#### My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output 
        method="html"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" 
    />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="titre">
        <div class="titre">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="texte1">
        <div class="texte1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <div class="al">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="i">
        <div class="italique">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="sup">
        <div class="sup">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="article">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title>Titre du document</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="presseCommerciale.css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
             <!-- START CONTENT -->
                <div class="ud-presseCommerciale">
                    <div class="article">
                        <div class="head">
                            <div class="pub">Bus &amp; Car</div>
                            <div class="rub">
                                <div class="inserted-text">Rubrique : </div>
                            <xsl:value-of select="head/rub"/></div>
                            <div class="auteur">
                                <div class="inserted-text">Auteur(s) : </div>
                                <div class="fonction default"><xsl:value-of select="head/auteur/fonction"/></div>
                                <div class="aut"><xsl:value-of select="head/auteur/aut"/></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- END CONTENT -->
            </body>
        </html> 
    </xsl:template>
```

The problem I have now is that the HTML special characters are deleted in my output.
I hope my code makes it clearer.

Comment: This is confusing. Please provide a [mcve] showing input, XSLT and expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry about the confusion. I've added my input and xslt. The expected output is the html in xslt. It works fine, except for the html special chars.

Comment: **1.** Where is `wk-presse.dtd`? Is it available to the XML parser?  **2.** Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: P.S. AFAICT, this has nothing to do with "i tag in p tag" and everything to do with HTML entities.

Comment: the dtd is available to the XML parser. I'm using libxslt.

Comment: Then please add it to your question, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: To you, my xslt seems correct?

Comment: I did not look at your XSLT. I see a problem in your input. The processor is either not seeing your DTD or ignoring it.

Comment: So you'd need wk-presse.dtd? What I don't get is that when I output my content with, for example, <xsl: value-of select="p"/> I have the actual html special characters output such as "&eacute;" but when I use <xsl: copy>, the special chars are missing. Can you explain this to me please?

Comment: I think it's clear that your processor tries to replace the entities with their equivalents and fails. Instead of throwing an error, it outputs a null string instead. I am not sure what the "correct" result is in such case.

Comment: Should I add my entities in my xslt?

Comment: That won't do any good. But if you can add them to the XML (i.e. make your DTD internal), that should work.